# Background services closed in aggressive doze mode and normal doze mode in 7.0

Tags: android

I have a background service that is somehow killed everyone device goes in doze mode. I have tried to make it STICKY, set up a Alarm to start the service if it removed from tasks or killed and even used the setAndAllowWhileIdle() to fire the intent to start the service all in vain. Can anyone help?

Comment: use JobScheduler it is specially desinged for this

Comment: @AJay I implemented it but it's really slow. The task now takes a long time to execute than a Background service

Comment: because of doze mode.

Comment: @AJay that happens in lollipop too. And I can't see that service anywhere in the running services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possible solutions I came up with -

- Ask user to allow your app to **ignore battery optimizations**.
  Here's the code snippet -

```
    @TargetApi(23)
    void ignoreBatteryOptimizations() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            return;
        }


        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            String packageName = ctx.getPackageName();
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            if (!pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName)) {
              //Do something
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.wtf("IGNORE:BATTERY", ex);
        }


    }
```

- Start a **foreground service** with the aforementioned fix to make sure 99% uptime.